# ls with range name of file

Tags: command-line, terminal, ls

I have files with numeric as it's file name.

```
10asdfsfl.txt
11sdfkf.txt
20sdfdf.txt
22sdfdf.txt
30saadf.txt
40asdfdf.txt
51sadfsf.txt
62ddgfg.txt
```

if I use

```
ls -l [40-50]*
```

it returning list of files

```
10asdfsfl.txt
11sdfkf.txt
20sdfdf.txt
22sdfdf.txt
30saadf.txt
40asdfdf.txt
51sadfsf.txt
```

while my expectation it should returning list

```
40asdfdf.txt
```

any advise how could I get the result i wanted with this range file name?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` is not for numeric ranges – it's for single-character ranges only (e.g. a-z). So your `[40-50]` is interpreted like "the character `4` or `0-5` or `0`", matching all files whose *first* character of the name is within the range.

There is no direct equivalent for numeric ranges, but `{}` can be used to generate a series of wildcards (some of which will match nothing so you'll probably want to use the 'nullglob' option at the same time), e.g. `{40..50}*` will expand to `40* 41* ... 50*`.

```
echo {40..50}xyz

echo {40..50}*

shopt -s nullglob
echo {40..50}*
shopt -u nullglob
```

If this is Bash and the 'extglob' option is enabled, you could do `@(4[0-9]|50)*` for a regex-like "either 4[0-9] or 50"… though that's not much better than just specifying both wildcards separately.

```
echo 4[0-9]* 50*

shopt -s extglob
echo @(4[0-9]|50)*
```

Comment: ah I see
so there's no 'ls` parameter that can produce my expected result then.

thank you

Comment: @snydez: Wildcards are not `ls` parameters in the first place. They're a shell thing that works independently from the command being run.